# php form using array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to create a form using array that user can select a number and echoes the number's corresponding object name after submit. I don't know why this code does not work, could someone please teach me how to do it the right way :( Thank you so much for your time.

```
<form name="train" method="GET" action="test.php">

<select name="object">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="all">Show All</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" size="10">
</form>

<?php

$train[0] = "pencil";
$train[1] = "macaron";
$train[2] = "notes";
$train[3] = "book";
$train[4] = "eraser";
$train[5] = "cake";
$train[6] = "laptop";
$train[7] = "mint";
$train[8] = "cup";

if ($_GET['submit']) { 
$train = $_GET['obejct']; 

echo "<p>I have $train!</p>";
}

 ?>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're setting `$train` to the value of whatever the form passes for the "object" select field, and then echoing that. You would expect then to see a number between 0 and 8, or the word "all" print out, but your reference of the object key has the word "object" misspelled as "obejct", so my guess is you're getting nothing to print as the value of `$train`.

Either way, what you really want to do is print the value at the key in the `$train` array that corresponds with what was provided by the user. This means that once you've created your array, which functions as a map, you must select the item from the array that you want to print.

You also need to handle the "all" case or you will get an error.

Here's how it would look if you continue using the array option:

```
<form name="train" method="GET" action="test.php">

<select name="object">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="all">Show All</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" size="10">
</form>

<?php

$train[0] = "pencil";
$train[1] = "macaron";
$train[2] = "notes";
$train[3] = "book";
$train[4] = "eraser";
$train[5] = "cake";
$train[6] = "laptop";
$train[7] = "mint";
$train[8] = "cup";

if ($_GET['submit']) {

    if ($_GET['object'] != 'all') {
        //Handle the non-all case
        $value = $train[$_GET['object']]; //This references a key in your array, like $train[0]
        echo "<p>I have $value!</p>";
    } else {
        //Handle the all case here
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Fastest gun in the west. +1